# How to looping in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, fetch, do-while

Source Code:

```
var req = require('request');
var input1 = require('readline-sync');
var usr = input1.question("User: ");
var api_url = 'https://api.simsimi.net/v2/?text=' +usr+'?&lc=id'
async function getISS() {
        const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const data = await response.json();
    const { success } = data;
    console.log("Simi: " +success);
    }
getISS()
```

how to display a loop like this, example:
User:

Sim:
if simi has answered it automatically stops

how do you do it so that when the simi output comes out, the user can enter the input again?
so like this

User:

Simi:

User:

Simi:

and keep repeating. Thanks

I hope to find the answer

Comment: do you mean an infinite loop like: `while (true) { await getISS(); }`?

Comment: So you want to receive user input and then use this input in the API call, all that in a loop? Then both `var usr` and `var api_url` lines need to be inside `getISS`. Then, the suggestion from Diego D can be applied.

Comment: Can you send the response coming from the API ?